# Flutter: How can I keep my last last ..shuffle order in a new state?

Tags: flutter, gridview, state, shuffle

Is there a way to keep an aspect of the page from updating when the State updates? Or to keep an instance of the ..shuffle so that I can re-use that shuffle order in the new state?

I have a GridView that fills up with items from a Map. These items are shuffled first to make them come in a different order each time people open that page.

Once they click on one of the items in the GridView I want to update the State so that I can change parts of the page...but I don't want to re-shuffle the map.

Is there any way to do this?

The Map and shuffle part of the code is like this:

```
    final Map choices = {
      'apple': selectSuccess,
      'orange': selectFailure,
      'cherry': selectFailure,
      'banana': selectFailure,
    };
    choices.forEach((k, v) => choiceSet.add(SelectCardActivity(k, v)));
    choiceSet..shuffle();
```

Comment: Don't do the shuffle in the build.  Do it in initState.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Those dynamic values couldn't manage in init so I changed them to strings and now it is working nicely.